# Searching for row number to update cell, update is working but in wrong row?? VBA Userforms

Tags: excel, vba

In a VBA Userform- when a new sale is to be entered in the Incomes worksheet,the user first selects an Artist from Combobox1, this populates combobox2 with his artworks from the inventory work sheet. Then the sales in written to incomes sheet.
This is all working great.
I then call the get row number function

I need to search the inventory table for 1: the correct artist and 2: artwork we just sold and if found return the Row number.
I want update this row and update the sold Col to "Y"

I am succcesfully searching for both criteria and getting a match and a row number!
The update is also working,  **but** in the wrong row.. it updates 2 rows down..
is it something to do with the offset?
but this where my meagre knowledge of VBA and Excel is wanting so any help please.. it must be a simple mod but what? Code below..

```
    Private Sub GetRowNumber()
    Dim Found As Range, Firstfound As String
    Dim rngSearch As Range
    Dim ArtistVal As String
    ArtistVal = ddlArtist.Value
    Dim ArtVal As String
    ArtVal = ddlArtwork.Value
    
    
   
    Set rngSearch = shInventory.Range("C:C")
       
    Set Found = rngSearch.Find(what:=ArtVal, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
       
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
        Firstfound = Found.Address
        Do
            If Found.EntireRow.Range("B1").Value = ArtistVal Then Exit Do  'Match found
            Set Found = rngSearch.FindNext(after:=Found)
            If Found.Address = Firstfound Then Set Found = Nothing
            Loop Until Found Is Nothing
    End If
    If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    'MsgBox "Found `ArtVal` at row " & Found.row
       Call WriteSoldUpdatateToInvetory(Found.row)
        
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing matched both criteria. ", , "No Match Found"
    End If
End Sub

 
Public Sub WriteSoldUpdatateToInvetory(ByVal m_currentRow As Long)

    With shInventory.Range("A2").offset(m_currentRow)
    .Cells(1, 8).Value = "Y"
   
    End With

End Sub
```

Haha, I got excited there but after changing the typo it is still updating 2 rows down?

Ok I have tried playing with the offset starting the range at A1 and adding -1 to current row val.. and it is working...
but not sure if it the correct or best way, so any advice is appreciated

```
With shInventory.Range("A1").Offset(m_currentRow - 1)
.Cells(1, 8).Value = "Y"

End With
```

Comment: `ofset(m_currentRow)` --> `Offset(m_currentRow)`

Comment: `shInventory.Cells(m_currentRow, 8).Value = "Y"`